# Custom RowLayout and a custom layout file for ListActivity crashing. LogCat Included

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, listactivity, android-logcat

I am using a ListActivity but it does not take the custom Adapter and crashes when I Use it.
Code here:
**FilesMenu.java**

```
package com.handyapp.filesaggregator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FilesMenu extends ListActivity {
    public static Context con;
    Map<String,File> dirMap;
    ArrayList<String> dirs;
    File[] files;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //this.
        SharedPreferences prefs=(SharedPreferences) getSharedPreferences("OFFSET",MODE_PRIVATE);
        con=this;
        File sdCard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        fileOp(sdCard);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_files_menu);
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter<String>(con,R.layout.item_list,R.id.txt1,dirs));
        getListView().setSelection(prefs.getInt("OFFSET_LIST",0));
        this.getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {  
                new FilesCollectorTask().execute(dirMap.get(dirs.get(position)));
                return false;
            }
        });
        new AlertDialog.Builder(con)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.exclmark)
        .setMessage("INSTRUCTIONS:\n1. This is just a BETA release"
                +"\n2. To organize a particular folder, Long click the folder and wait"
                +"\n3. And i repeat again, this is just a beta release, big folders take quite a lot of time to finish,PLEASE be patient"
                +"\n4. creator:Abdul Hannan Kanji :P")
                .setNeutralButton("Got it!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();


    }
    private void fileOp(File root)
    {
        files=root.listFiles();
        dirs=new ArrayList<String>();
        dirMap=new HashMap<String,File>();
        dirs.add("...");
        dirMap.put("...", root.getParentFile());
        if(files!=null)
        {
        for(File file : files)
        {
            if(file!=null&&file.isDirectory())
            {
                dirs.add(file.getName());
                dirMap.put(file.getName(), file);
            }

        }
        }
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v,int position,long id)
    {
        try {
            fileOp(dirMap.get(dirs.get(position)));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //int pos=this.getListView().getBaseline();
        SharedPreferences prefs=(SharedPreferences) con.getSharedPreferences("OFFSET", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("OFFSET_LIST", position);
        editor.commit();
        parent.setAdapter(new MyAdapter<String>(con,R.layout.item_list,R.id.txt1,dirs));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_files_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class FilesCollectorTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCancelled();
            dialog.dismiss();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(con)
            .setMessage("Operation Unsuccessful!Make sure you have enough memeory in your external storage")
            .setNeutralButton("Dismiss", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.exclmark);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog=ProgressDialog.show(con, "Aggregating Files", "Please wait...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(File... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(params==null || params.length==0)
            {
                this.cancel(true);
            }
            try {
                //Toast.makeText(con,params[0].getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                FileOperation.doWithFiles(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(con, "IOException ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.cancel(true);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    Context con;
    ArrayList<String> items;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (T)items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row;
        TextView tv;
        LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            row=inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent);
        }
        else
        {
            row=convertView;
        }
        tv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        tv.setText(items.get(position));
        return row;
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context,int resource,int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        con=context;
        items=objects;
    }
}
```

**activity_files_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dip"
               android:background="@drawable/ambience"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**item_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:textColor="#D2DCEE"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder_small"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
01-15 14:03:50.586: D/dalvikvm(579): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 69K, 52% free 2632K/5379K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 78ms
01-15 14:03:51.096: D/AndroidRuntime(579): Shutting down VM
01-15 14:03:51.096: W/dalvikvm(579): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #6: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3598)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3678)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1400)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1326)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:47)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:625)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.handyapp.filesaggregator.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:42)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1290)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1588)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-15 14:03:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if its not possible, Any other easier way to do do it?
EDIT:
After including layout_width attribute, the following error is coming:
**logCat**

```
01-15 14:22:38.246: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 70K, 52% free 2632K/5379K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 89ms
01-15 14:22:38.826: D/AndroidRuntime(614): Shutting down VM
01-15 14:22:38.826: W/dalvikvm(614): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:461)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:416)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.handyapp.filesaggregator.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:42)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1290)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1588)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-15 14:22:38.846: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Binary XML file line #6: You must supply a layout_width attribute
```

You must specify the android:layout_width attribute:

```
...
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:alpha="0"
    android:textColor="#D2DCEE"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder_small"/>
```

Comment: Yeah i did. i just reaslised after posting it. But now getting another error while inflating the layout file. including logcat now

Answer (score 0):

`Logcat` tell me you forget to put `layout_width` and `layout_height` value in `item_list.xml`.

Try changing `item_list.xml` to something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#D2DCEE"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder_small"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Try putting `false` parameter while you inflate. `row=inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);` or replacing parent parameter with null like this `row=inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_list,null);`